# How todisable keyboard in react-datetime

Tags: reactjs, react-datepicker

I'm using [react date time](https://github.com/arqex/react-datetime) to select a year.
The problem is if I press any button with keyboard, it shows an error.
Is there a way to disable keyboard on that input?

```
 <Datetime initialValue='' timeFormat={false} dateFormat="YYYY" onChange={(date) => setYear(date.year())} />
```

thank you

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue once. Passing readyOnly prop to the component solved it for me.

InputProps={{readOnly: true}}

Comment: it didn't work for me :(

Answer (score 0):

It worked like this

```
<Datetime initialValue='' timeFormat={false} dateFormat="YYYY" onChange={(date) => setYear(date.year())} inputProps={{ onKeyDown: (e) => { e.preventDefault() } }} />
```